# Label above table

Tags: html, css

So I have this

```
echo   
"<div class=''>
 <table class='table' border='1'>
     <tr class='head'>

     <th>Section Name</th>
     <th></th>
     <th>Ae</th>
     <th>Pt</th>
     <th>Prin</th>
```

How can I get a nice LABEL above it that looks like its apart of the table, But it is centered in the middle above the THs I want this to represent the Tables Name, For instance it will say. Table 1 centered and above this table but still in the borders of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another row with a colspan for your number of columns.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="5" class="label">Table 1</td>
   </tr>
   ... Your table ...
</table>
```

You can center the text with CSS.

```
.label {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Your answer was correct, Using the answer you provided it did exactly what I need to do without having to re-do borders and everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'd insert a [`<caption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption) element between the opening `<table>` element and the first `<tr>` like:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <caption>Table 1</caption>
    <tr>...
```

The `<caption>` was pretty much made for this:

> The HTML `<caption>` Element (or HTML Table Caption Element)
>   represents the title of a table.Though it is always the first descendant of a `<table>`, its styling, using CSS, may place it elsewhere, relative to the table.

Comment: Huh, TIL! Had no clue this element existed. Is it HTML5?

Comment: Nope, been around since 4.

Comment: but how do I keep it looking apart of the table, Same borders and style, just centered top middle.

Comment: @j08691 cause when I do that, It just sets standard font above my table.

Comment: Like if I was using <h1> tags

Comment: You can style the caption as you do any other element, including adding borders etc. Depends on your CSS and HTML.

Comment: this should be the answer :) .... beside you have caption-side in css to put it on any side of table ... still doesn't work cross browser (css)  :(  You may even use the summary attribute to generate it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrmegP  see for relevant info https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/caption-summary/

Comment: This is a good answer yes, It is not the answer to my question though. I wanted to be able to do it while keeping the borders and font the same without having to change more stuff in CSS, The answer I accepted did just that for me.

Comment: The caption element requires you to set the borders and font the same as the table because it only prints it like a "caption" standard font right above the table.